# sort files inside sub folders by name like the OS does

Tags: python, operating-system

I really tried figuring out this one, but without success.
I downloaded a course materials, and it's in the following format:

```
D:\course\day1\1.1\video1.mp4,..,video20.mp4
..
D:\course\day1\1.9\video1.mp4,..,video19.mp4
D:\course\day1\1.10
..
D:\course\day1\1.20
..
D:\course\day5\5.1\video1.mp4,..,video15.mp4
..
D:\course\day1\5.19\
```

Now, because I have many video files, 150+ each day - I wanted to merge them into a single .mp4 file of each day.
So I had an external program but the way it shows the file is different than the OS for example:

video1, video10, video2
the 10 is not after 9 but after 1 lol
it's the same with the subfolders, for example 5.1 and 5.10.
So I wanted to rename them using a python code but when I entered them into a list, it's the same with python as it was in my external tool.

my idea was to rename the files to a.mp4
and then a += "a" for the second file.
It worked great, I don't mind having 150 files all called a up to the last file which was 150 "a".
but as mentioned, my issue was that python saw the files and sub folders as 1 and then 10 instead of 2.

Hope you understand..
I wanted to sort the sub folders and files in a good order and then rename them.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of (https://stackoverflow.com/q/4836710)